# I need convert a decimal to int in a linq statement

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I have this linq statement.

```
var sum = from l in list
select new
{
    Sum = (l.sum + .005) * 1000
};
```

this line won't work:

```
Sum = (l.sum + .005) * 1000
```

because sum is a decimal.

I would like to use `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions` but there is no `Convert` or `Cast`...

Is there any way i can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see the issue is that `0.005` is a `double` and not that `l.sum` is a `decimal`. Your code should work if you change it like this:

```
var sum = from l in list
select new
{
    Sum = (l.sum + .005M) * 1000
};
```

Note the `M` after `.005`

Comment: It explicitly tells the compiler that the value is a `decimal`, otherwise it infers it as a `double`.